# Grep while excluding special letters like umlauts

Tags: regex, bash, grep, diacritics

I'm running Mint Xfce and attempting to grep from terminal using the following:

```
grep -E -o '^[A-Za-z]{1,}\s[A-Za-z]{1,}\s[0-9]{1,}' sourcefile.txt | sort -f > newfile.txt
```

The source file is a text file where each line looks like

```
<string><space><string><tab><number><tab><number><tab>...
```

where the strings have letters, numbers, punctuation, and special characters and the numbers are integers.

My goal is to extract the two strings and first number for **just the lines where the strings contain only English letters** (a-z, upper or lower case).

The above command leaves out strings with punctuation and numbers, but lines where the strings have special letters like u umlauts (Ü) are somehow getting through and being sent to newfile.txt. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but a ton of Googling only gives me back discussions on how to grep for special letters. I've tested the regex at https://regex101.com/ and umlauts don't get matched, which makes me think the problem isn't with my regex.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to temporary change Locale.
Try:

```
LC_ALL="C" grep -E -o '^[A-Za-z]{1,}\s[A-Za-z]{1,}\s[0-9]{1,}' sourcefile.txt | sort -f > newfile.txt
```

It worked for me on Ubuntu.
To switch back to your Locale simply close the console window.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why it didn't work the first way, but it works now.

Comment: In a fresh console window, if you type `echo $LC_NAME`, you will not see `C` as the output, but, I bet, your language preferences together with UTF-8. `LC_ALL` temporary overrides `LC_*` variables.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to fudge any of that `LOCALE` stuff :

```
echo '<string1><space><string2><tab><number1><tab><number2><tab>...' |
```

> ```
> gawk 'NF = 3*!/[^\0-\177]/' OFS='\n' FS='<(space|tab)>' # the demo delims
>
> mawk 'NF = 3*!/[^\0-\177]/' OFS='\n'                    # the actual delims
> ```

```
<string1>
<string2>
<number1>
```

By doing it as a multiply, it sets `NF` to either `3` if it's `ASCII` or `0` if any multi-byte `Unicode` detected thus scrubbing the entire line clean instead.

If youre pedantic about guarding against `non-Unicode`-compliant random binary bytes while using `gawk` unicode mode, then try

> ```
> gawk 'NF = 3*/^[\0-\177]+$/'
> ```

But if you ***INSIST*** on only using `nawk` instead of the other 2, then add a pair of `( )` ::

> ```
> nawk 'NF = 3*(!/[^\0-\177]/)' OFS='\n'
> ```

to circumvent the fatal error arising from its buggy parser, despite the code itself being `POSIX`-compliant